# How to use a local font file in a create-react-app project

Tags: css, reactjs

In my react project created using `create-react-app`, I put a font file called `CaviarDreams.ttf` inside my `/asset` folder.

In the default `index.css` file, I did like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CaviarDreams';
  src: url('assets/CaviarDreams.ttf') format('truetype'),
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "CaviarDreams";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

However, the font doesn't change at all.
I also tried in the `App.css`, but it's still the same.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ttf format doesnt support 100% for the Web.

You have to convert the desktop fonts to web fonts before use in Web.

Try - https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator (**Online Webfont Generator**)

and download the web fonts and add the css accordingly.

Comment: Is this the only way? My font file somehow got corrupted

Comment: there may be more than one file. please check. also check for chrome console errors